# How do I list my foreign keys in my customer registration view with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Is the relationship working in the bank, but I can't show it in my registration view?

Usuario.php

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'company',
    'name',
    'document',
    'phone',
    'email'
];

public function empresa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Empresa');
}}
```

Empresa.php

```
class Empresa extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'uf',
    'cnpj'
];

public function usuarios()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Usuario');
}}
```

form.blade.php

```
   @foreach($usuarios as $u)

   <option value="{{ $u->company_id->name }}">{{ $u->company_id->name }}</option>
                        
   @endforeach
```

UsuarioController.php

```
class UsuariosController extends Controller
{

public function new(){
    $usuarios = Usuario::get();
    return view('usuarios.form', ['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A8S5.jpg)

Comment: can you be more clear on what are you trying to achieve?, you can't show what?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry. I am registering a customer list, each customer belongs to a company. I would like the companies I have registered to appear on the customer registration form. But they don't appear, my <select> appears empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change your empresa() method in Usuario class.

```
public function empresa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Empresa', 'company');
}
```

and blade file will be changes like this.

```
@foreach($usuarios as $u)

   <option value="{{ $u->empresa->name }}">{{ $u->empresa->name }}</option>
                        
@endforeach
```

Comment: The name appears correct, but the name of the company only comes when I register a user directly through the database, I would like him to search for the name of the company right after I register a company. I'm sending the updated code. Thanks

Comment: if this answers your question then please approve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

form.blade.php

```
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Empresa:</label>
                        <select name="company" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($usuarios as $u)

                        <option value="{{ $u->empresa->name }}">{{ $u->empresa->name }}</option>
                        
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

UsuarioController.

> 

```
class UsuariosController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $usuarios = Usuario::get();
    return view('usuarios.list', ['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
}

public function new(){
    $usuarios = Usuario::get();
    return view('usuarios.form', ['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
}

public function adicionar( Request $request ){

    $usuario = new Usuario;
    $usuarios = Usuario::get();
    $usuario = $usuario->create( $request->all() );
    return Redirect::to('/usuarios', ['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
}

public function editar( $id ){
    $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail( $id );
    return view('usuarios.form', ['usuario' => $usuario]);
```